# Boost c++ libraries supported for Mac OS 10.5.8 Leopard?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, boost

Which is the latest Boost C++ library supported for MAC OS 10.5.8 Leopard officially?
I have gcc version 4.0.1.

I'm able to compile Boost 1.47 with above configuration, but I suspect it might lead to future complications if not supported officially?

Can you please tell me which is the latest Boost version supported for above configuration.

Thank you.

Comment: I normally get boost more recent versions of gcc from macports.org. It isn't "official" though but may be worth giving a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the latest version of Boost that was officially tested with GCC 4.01 on OS X was [1.46.0](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_46_0.html).